# How to get objects constant in List<Objects> by Key Object of Map<Objects,Value>

Tags: java

I have one `List<Person>` I Want to get Person's Objects have Job is Software And I have `Map<Person, String>` , Key Stored Objects have Job is software . I 
want get Objects Person in that List by Key of Map I try to use Java 8

```
 Exp: 
      List<Person> listPerson = new ArrayList<>();
      Person personone = Person();
      personone.setJob("teacher");
      personone.setName("Peter");
      Personone.setAge("23");

     Person persontwo = Person();
     persontwo.setJob("software");
     persontwo.setName("July");
     persontwo.setAge("25");

     Person personthree = Person();
     personthree.setJob("software");
     personthree.setName("John");
     personthree.setAge("26");

     Person personfour = Person();
     personfour.setJob("Singer");
     personfour.setName("mina");
     personfour.setAge("30");

     listPerson.add(personone);
     listPerson.add(persontwo);
     listPerson.add(personthree);
     listPerson.add(personfour);


    Map<Person,String> mapPerson = new HashMap<>();
    mapPerson.put(personone,"abc");
    mapPerson.put(persontwo,"abcoo"); 
    mapPerson.put(personthree,"abgh"); 
    mapPerson.put(personfour,"abgh22");
```

Comment: Define "person's objects"

Comment: Can you share your code where are you trying to it?